# Styling different paragraphs with different styles using CSS and HTML

Tags: css, html, class, styles

I have a question on using the class tag on paragraph tags. I want the external Css file to style a paragraph  a certain way while leaving all the other paragraphs to the default style.I did some googling and reading and found if i add `<p class="somename" >` then in the css file i can change that paragraph using `p.somename{ color: blue;}`
But what i found is `p{color: red;}` seems to be affecting them all.

This was just a example problem. The main problem im facing is that i dont want p.somename to have a background border.And the default `<p>` has borders.

Comment: Thats right. Whats the question now?

Comment: i want paragraphs with class somename to be blue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the implications of using "!important" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML,

```
<p id="colorblue">some lorem ipsum here</p>
```

In CSS,

```
 p #colorblue{
color: blue
}
```

Or tepkenvannkorn's answer will work.

```
p.somename { color: blue !important; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Put `p.somename{ color: blue }` to the bottom comparing to `p{ color: red}` or you can use `!important` to foce your style to overwrite. for example,

```
p.somename {
   color: blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only use that id on the paragraph that you want to change, while keeping others at default

```
    p #colorred{
    color:red
    }
    <p id="colorred">
```

Comment: can u expand on this? im kinda confused on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

/*
In HTML,

```
<p id="colorblue">some lorem ipsum here</p>
```

In CSS,

```
#colorblue {
 color:blue;
}
```

This works. You do not need to explain that is a paragraph in CSS. Only write the ID of the paragraph in CSS.*/