# p tag already styled for one page but I want to style it differently for another page

Tags: html, css

On my homepage I have images with a hover effect and text appears as a hover styled with the P tag, so thats all working fine.

However on my about page I am trying to add text and split it up using P however as I already have the P styled for the home page the P element in the about page is taking the styling for the home page.

**I tried adding a class for P in about.html but that did not work.**

Any ideas how I can have the P tag with 2 different types of styling ?

I cant even get the the text on about.html to display.

Heres my code for the index.html

```
p {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: white;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
    width: 97%;
}
p .heading {
    color: #FFD829;
    display: block;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

p a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFD829;
}
p img {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
p iframe {
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: from head inside <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

Comment: how is styling made for that home page? In css file? Maybe your about.html is also using the same file as source of styles?

Comment: @JanWalczak it looks like he didn't created css file. He used <style>...</style>

Comment: This question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266501/styling-different-paragraphs-with-different-styles-using-css-and-html)

Comment: without your html code, hard to guess if a  selector with a higher specifity will do or if other ways are required. ...

Comment: @Kimiasn Op says he tried adding a class and that it failed :)

Comment: instead of a class use an id. Also place the class/id rule AFTER the standard `P` rule...

Answer (score 0):

you have two mean to do what you expect : 
If you want to modify several p tags with the same design, you can add a class all these p tags and then in a style tag or an external stylesheet design differently your tags.

for sample in your about.html

```
<p class="newStyle"></p>
```

in your css

```
.newStyle {
  //your attributes
}
```

if you want another design for only one p tag you can used the id attributes on this and the design will be apply to only this p tag (be carefull id must be unique in your page)

html

```
<p id="newStyle"></p>
```

css :

```
#newStyle {
      //your attributes
    }
```

> If your are using a style tag inside your html you can validate your page with a W3C validator to make sure you have no issue in it : 
>   https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input
>
> if you are using an external stylesheet be sure to include it in your page with the link tag :
>
> It exist also a css validator you can used to check you have no make mistake in it :
>   https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: the op said he tried it and failed .... we need more infos to give some usefull answers ;)

Comment: yes totally for the moment we can only give him element to analyze his own code.

Answer (score -1):

Just delete `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` from Your `about.html` page. And later added P definitions will work.

Answer (score -1):

1) Create 2 classes

```
p.home

p.about
```

2)You can override previous applied styles by using `!important`